# Unexpected error occurring on PHP file regeneration MacOS only, not windows

Tags: php

The regeneration of our file after deleting an item from our database causes the following error on Mac only:

> syntax error, unexpected ''import_price_rules' => 'Impor' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting end of file

The exact place of the error changes and is not specific to the actual error, for example depending on which translation file it occurs on it may be a different place within that file.

We believe the error might be due to the following line:

```
File::put($translationFilePath, "<?php\n\nreturn " . StringHelper::varExportFormat(var_export($translations, true)) . PHP_EOL);
```

We have narrowed it down to possibly being due to `var_export`.

We thought it would be due to the line breaking but we are all on the same settings.

Again this code works absolutely fine on Windows and the error only occurs on Mac.